# Why do I sometimes get a strange address in a pointer

Tags: c++

So, I am working with C++ and openFrameworks. And sometimes when I try to get a pointer to an instance of a class, normally I get something like this (00000000038468B0). Or when it is not there it returns a nullptr. Everything is programmed, so the value can either be a nullptr, or refer to an actual instance.

I do that by always setting the value of the pointer to a nullptr in the header file.

```
someClass* someInstance = nullptr;
```

And when I delete an instance I always set it back to nullptr in any reference to this instance.

But sometimes the pointer returns DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD, which means the application will crash because it will pass my safety if statements that check whether or not the pointer is a nullptr before doing something with it.

Anyone have an idea what DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD is? I cant seem to find any information about it...

Comment: Typically values such as this, and `0xCDCDCDCD`, `0xDEADBEEF`, etc are chosen for debug purposes so that they are invalid addresses which will guarantee an exception if de-referenced, rather than leaving open the possibility that the uninitialised pointer might happen to point at a valid address.

Comment: Your compiler makes this strange pointers to help differentiate them in debug mode.

Comment: Depends on your compiler, but it's likely you have an uninitilized pointer.

Comment: It's probably a magic number; probably a helpful way of telling you a pointer is uninitialised. My favourite is BADC0FFEE0DDF00D. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: you have an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am going to see if I can find what causes this. I just edited the original question. I explain there I always set every instance to a nullptr in the header file. So it should always be initialized as a nullptr right?

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD` is used internally by Microsoft .NET `free()` to mark a freed pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this page: [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html)

> Mnemonics for remembering what each fill-pattern means:
>
> The newly allocated memory (0x**C**D) is Clean memory.
>
> The free()d memory (0x**D**D) is Dead memory.
>
> The guard bytes (0x**F**D) are like Fences around your memory.

So, assuming your platform is Win32, then it would appear that the memory where the pointer resides was freed.

It suggests that you've been accessing invalid memory in which case you will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer itself must be a member within some other object.  The entire object that the pointer is a member of has been deleted, but you are still using it.

So looking at the use of the pointer with the symptoms and the deletions and creations of the thing it points to is all one level away from the problem.

You should be looking for the deletion of the object that the pointer is a member of.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to see if I might have overlooked something. The whole reason I didnt post any specific code is because the whole situation would take me too long to explain. 

It helps a lot that I am sure now what exactly this DDDD is standing for.

Answer (score 1):

myHello is an object pointer
and conc_2D_P is a method here

```
cout << "Check1 " << (myHello->conc_2D_P);
delete myHello;
cout << "Check2 " << (myHello->conc_2D_P)<<endl;
```

upon running this snippet we get output as

Check1  0000017C3EF89A70

Check2  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

In the second line of code we delete the entire object pointer but in the next line we are again trying to access it and consequently DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD.